# Move a module variable inside a default export of a JavaScript module?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm writing a plugin in the form of a default export like the code below. I want to be able to pass an object as default plugin options, this way:

```
// Normal call without options
Alpine.plugin(MyPlugin);

// Call with options
Alpine.plugin(MyPlugin.defaults({ foo: "bar" }));
```

I can easly solve adding `let defaultOptions` outside the scope of the plugin itself (that is, in the root of the module):

```
// src/myplugin.ts

let defaultOptions: MyPluginOptions;

const MyPlugin = (Alpine: Alpine) => {
  // Use defaultOptions here
};

// Expose a way to set default options
MyPlugin.defaults = (options: MyPluginOptions) => {
  defaultOptions = options;

  return MyPlugin;
};

export default MyPlugin;
```

Do I have any other option to move it inside the plugin itself?

Comment: Calling `MyPlugin.defaults` should not globally set the `defaultOptions` for all usages of the plugin. Instead, it should create a *new* plugin that is configured with those defaults.

Comment: On that note: just make `MyPlugin` a normal class, not a const-function? Then you get a constructor that you can pass those optional defaultOptions to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `MyPlugin.defaults`, if used like this, should not globally set the `defaultOptions` for all usages of the plugin. Instead, it should create a *new* plugin that is configured with those defaults. You can use the factory pattern for this:

```
type Plugin = {
  // basic call signature
  (_: Alpine): void;
  // extend options
  withDefaults(options: MyPluginOptions): Plugin;
}

function makeMyPlugin(defaultOptions: MyPluginOptions): Plugin {
  const MyPlugin = (Alpine: Alpine) => {
    // Use defaultOptions here
  };

  // Expose a way to create a new plugin with extended default options
  MyPlugin.withDefaults = (options: MyPluginOptions): Plugin => {
    return makeMyMyPlugin({...defaultOptions, ...options});
  };

  return MyPlugin;
}

export default makeMyPlugin({});
```

This even lets you chain the plugin creation:

```
const pluginA = MyPlugin.withDefault({foo: "bar"});
const pluginB = pluginA.withDefaults({baz: "quux"});
const pluginC = MyPlugin.withDefaults({foo: "quux"}).withDefaults({baz: "bar"});
const pluginD = MyPlugin;
```

Comment: Nice, I'll try it right now. Just a note: plugin will be invoked just one time, calling and adding it two times would be an incorrect usage!

Comment: @gremo You should be able to call/instantiate it many times, e.g. during tests, without the usages affecting each other. Maybe they should not be used multiple times on the same `Alpine` instance, but I don't know what `Alpine` is

Comment: Right, right. There is no need to know about Alpine, it's just a framework.

Comment: Really clean and elegant solution, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you can move the `defaultOptions` variable inside the plugin itself by using a closure to encapsulate the variable within the scope of the `MyPlugin` function.

```
const MyPlugin = (Alpine: Alpine) => {
  let defaultOptions: MyPluginOptions;

  // Use defaultOptions here

  // Expose a way to set default options
  MyPlugin.defaults = (options: MyPluginOptions) => {
    defaultOptions = options;
    return MyPlugin;
  };

  return MyPlugin;
};

export default MyPlugin;
```

Comment: This causes a `TypeError: MyPlugin.defaults is not a function` because `defaults` is not yet defined before `MyPlugin` is called